# TCP Multi-Thread Server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am ttrying to implement a multithread TCP server using Python. When I run the following code I obtain the following error:

## Error

```
Incoming message: how are you
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function client_thread at 0x00000000024499 E8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tcp_test2.py", line 32, in client_thread
message = recv_msg(conn)
File "tcp_test2.py", line 24, in recv_msg
raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
File "tcp_test2.py", line 13, in recvall
raise EOFError('was expecting %d bytes but only received %d bytes before socket closed' % (length, len(data)))
EOFError: was expecting 4 bytes but only received 0 bytes before socket closed
```

Not sure where I am going wrong with implementing the threading function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Code

```
import argparse
import socket
import struct
from thread import start_new_thread

def recvall(sock, length):
    data = b''
    while len(data) < length:
        packet = sock.recv(length - len(data))
        if not packet:
            raise EOFError('was expecting %d bytes but only received %d bytes before socket closed' % (length, len(data)))
        data += packet
    return data

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)


def recv_msg(sock):
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def client_thread(conn):
    while True:
        message = recv_msg(conn)
        print('Incoming message: {}'.format(message))
        conn.sendall(b'Message Received')  #send data to the socket
    conn.close()  #mark the socket closed
    print('\tReply sent, socket closed')
```

## Server

```
def server(interface, port):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((interface, port))  # the socket to address
    sock.listen(1)  #listen for connections made to the socket.
    while True:
        conn, sockname = sock.accept()
        start_new_thread(client_thread,(conn,))

    sock.close()
```

## Client

```
def client(host, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.connect((host, port))
    print('Client has been assigned socket name', sock.getsockname())
    message = raw_input("Type your message: ")
    send_msg(sock, message)
    reply = recvall(sock, 16)
    print('Server Response: {}'.format(reply))
    print('\nSocket closed')
    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choices = {'client': client, 'server': server}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Send and receive over TCP')
    parser.add_argument('role', choices=choices, help='which role to play')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='interface the sever listens at:' 'host the client sends to')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='PORT', type=int, default=1060, help='TCP port(default 1060)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function = choices[args.role]
    function(args.host, args.p)
```

This is my previous code which did not have any unhandled exceptions

```
import argparse
import socket
import struct

def recvall(sock, length):
    data = b''
    while len(data) < length:
        packet = sock.recv(length - len(data))
        if not packet:
            raise EOFError('was expecting %d bytes but only received %d bytes before socket closed' % (length, len(data)))
        data += packet
    return data

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)


def recv_msg(sock):
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    return recvall(sock, msglen)


def server(interface, port):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((interface, port))  # the socket to address
    sock.listen(1)  #listen for connections made to the socket.
    print('Listening at {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))  #returns the socket's own address
    while True:
        conn, sockname = sock.accept()
        print('Connection accepted from {}'.format(sockname))
        print('\tServer Socket: {}'.format(conn.getsockname()))
        print('\tClient Socket: {}'.format(conn.getpeername()))  # return remote address to which socket is connected
        message = recv_msg(conn)
        print('Incoming message: {}'.format(message))
        conn.sendall(b'Message Received')  #send data to the socket
        conn.close()  #mark the socket closed
        print('\tReply sent, socket closed')

def client(host, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
    print('Client has been assigned socket name', sock.getsockname())
    message = raw_input("Type your message: ")
    send_msg(sock, message)
    reply = recvall(sock, 16)
    print('Server Response: {}'.format(reply))
    print('\nSocket closed')
    sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    choices = {'client': client, 'server': server}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Send and receive over TCP')
    parser.add_argument('role', choices=choices, help='which role to play')
    parser.add_argument('host', help='interface the sever listens at:' 'host the client sends to')
    parser.add_argument('-p', metavar='PORT', type=int, default=1060, help='TCP port(default 1060)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function = choices[args.role]
    function(args.host, args.p)
```

Comment: I could provide a better answer if you explain what you expected to happen. The behavior you got is exactly what you should have expected.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. Your client closes the socket. The server detects this when it tries to read the next message. This should have been exactly what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I just dont understand why I am getting an unhandled exception with this code. Without the threading function I do not get this unhandled exception. I get only the desirable message that the client sent. I would like to be able to clean the output that is being displayed at the server.

Comment: Do you understand that your code raises an EOFError on normal close?

Comment: Yes I understand that EOFError will be raised when no more bytes are sent. But could you please explain to me why then is it considering it an unhandled exception?

I have posted my previous code which did not have any unhandled exception for comparison.

Comment: I honestly don't know what's not clear to you. Can you explain what you expected to happen? Do you understand that `raise` raises an exception? Do you understand that your code raises an exception when it detects a normal close? Do you think your code handles the exception? If you understand that your code raises an exception and know that you have no code to handle the exception, why does an unhandled exception error surprise you?